# PHP Email Attachment - Canvas Image BLANK

Tags: php, ajax, email, canvas

UPDATE: The image that I'm receiving is a blank image, the size of my canvas. It is not the image from the canvas. I am able to insert the new canvas PNG into the DOM, so I know the image data is good.

FURTHER: I can copy the image data before it sends to the PHP form, paste that code into an  tag on another page, as its src and the correct image displays! SO CLOSE HERE!!

My user creates an image on the HTML5 canvas. I need to send the image as an email attachment to the user. I can capture the image and POST it to a PHP page using jquery AJAX.

Yes, I have read the dozen or so other related posts which is how I got to this point. No - none of them answers my question - this part is always skipped. NO - I do not want to use PHPMailer (horrific documentation) or any of the other classes. This is possible using PHP mail(). And I'm close.

This is the javascript, in my web application:

```
var data = "to=" + to + "&subject=" + subject;          
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas");
var strDataURI = canvas2.toDataURL(); 
data = data + "&attachment="  + strDataURI;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail2.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){

        $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide();
        $('#message-sent').fadeIn(500).show();               
   }
});
```

POSTs this data:

```
 "to=erik@mydomain.com&subject=test&attachment=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA3gAAAHBCAYAAAA7NBnaAAA..."
```

To this PHP page (updated, more simple):

```
<?PHP    
$to =   $_REQUEST['to'];
$subject =  'PHP Mail Attachment Test';
$bound_text =   "jimmyP123";
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";


$attachment = $_REQUEST['attachment'];
$attachment =  substr($attachment,strpos($attachment,",")+1);
$attachment = chunk_split($attachment);



$headers =  "From: admin@server.com\r\n";
$headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .=     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
.$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
."hey my <b>good</b> friend here is a picture of regal beagle\r\n"
.$bound;

//$file =   file_get_contents("http://www.litfuel.net/php/regal_004.jpg");

$message .=     "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"index.png\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"index.png\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.$attachment
//.chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
.$bound_last;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
     echo 'MAIL SENT';
} else {
     echo 'MAIL FAILED';
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you also post the resulting mail (in plain text, of course)

Comment: Anyway, could you please post it in plain text

Comment: instead of using output buffering, try using heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: using heredoc, i've at least gotten an attachment -- however CANT view it. Can save it, cant view that either. New code coming.

Comment: The data of your image should just be the base64 encoded data.

Comment: aknosis - you are saying that i need to trim off "image/png;base64," correct? $attachment =  substr($attachment,strpos($attachment,",")+1);

Comment: so, trimming that off helps. however, im getting a blank image. it is not the image off the canvas, it is the background color of it. this is the same data (variable) i use to display the image on the "email" page, so i know a "flat" image is created i can see it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using a heredoc. That might be causing the issue here.

Line endings in emails MUST be `\r\n` (CRLF), so I would suggest rewriting it with string concatenation instead and then it should work.

Also, make sure that you apply `chunk_split()` on `$attachment` to keep the line length <= 76.

Comment: Thank you for the input, Jack. I'll try this in a few hours and report back.

Comment: Closer. The issue is getting the long string from the browser to the PHP page in tact. Something is awry.

Comment: @SlopesideCreative You forgot to apply `base64_encode()` on `$attachment` first before applying `chunk_split()`.

Comment: no luck. The data is already base64 encoded before the ajax post. I'll go back to this, for now I'm going the standard PHPmailer route as much as I'd rather not have to save the image to the server first - I know that can be done and need this done asap. @Jack

Comment: @SlopesideCreative Right, forgot about the fact that it comes in base64. If it's one contiguous string it should work, but without more data I can't tell.

Comment: Somewhere, the data string is broken along the way. With time, I'll track it down and this will work. Right now, I need to get a job launched even if it means storing the image on the server. Thank you for the inputs, helped get it this far/close. @Jack

Comment: The entire string makes it, however there are gaps in the string. Not just spaces, but gaps. All the data, just gaps. I heard a "+" sign might help join them or something?

Comment: @SlopesideCreative You can use `preg_replace('/s+/', '', $str);` to remove gaps; otherwise, I don't know what you mean and you would have to show a pastie or sth.